# AppFabric and DeadLetter Messages

Tags: azure, appfabric, azure-appfabric

The `BrokeredMessage` class has a method, called `DeadLetter()` which sends them to the [Dead-letter message queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.deadletter.aspx). One way to retrieve them at a later time is via their Receipt, but I was wondering if there are other ways to list all the messages inside the Dead Letter Queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example on the codeplex service bus site

http://servicebus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/6260#145774